# Attach de uma ClassLibrary à uma aplicação Externa (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, debug

Eu tenho um projeto que é uma ClassLibrary e essa DLL roda dentro de um Console Application, tenho um requisito aqui onde os desenvolvedores dessa ClassLibrary necessitam debugar essa DLL com a aplicação, nas propriedades do projeto eu configurei o caminho do EXE, executa normalmente porém os breakpoints não funcionam.

- Visual Studio rodando como administrador
- DLLs atualizadas na pasta do executável

[image]

**Porém, se eu rodar a aplicação manualmente (no mesmo caminho que configurei na imagem acima) e for através da opção Attach to Process os breakpoints funcionam**

Tentei também copiar a DLL e o PDB após o Build para garantir quando eu tiver alteraçõs o programa terá a versão recente (senão o attach não funciona corretamente). O que me parece aqui é que preciso de tipo um "delay" pra fazer o attach.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de algumas pesquisas resolvi criar um Helper para isso

O que eu fiz foi criar uma nova aplicação chamada DebuggerHelper, essa aplicação roda meu processo principal e faz attach automaticamente à ele.

Sendo assim eu adicionei esse Helper na propriedade Debug do meu Projeto ClassLibrary e adicionei o arquivo como parte do projeto.
Agora eu rodo minha DLL com F5 e o debug funciona perfeitamente.

Mais informações e detalhes abaixo:

[image]

```
private static void AttachProcess()
{
    var localByName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(_appName);

    MessageFilter.Register();
    var process = GetProcess(localByName[0].Id);
    if (process != null)
    {
        process.Attach();
        Console.WriteLine("Attached to {0}", process.Name);
    }
    MessageFilter.Revoke();
}

private static void StartProcess()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("start.bat");

    Console.WriteLine("Waiting to load the process...");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}

private static Process GetProcess(int processId)
{
    // Visual Studio 2017 (15.0)
    var dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0");
    var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses.OfType<Process>();
    return processes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProcessID == processId);
}
```

Github solution:
https://github.com/thiagoloureiro/DebuggerHelper